# Jersey Rest api : How to explicitly handle exception in case the input xml is not in correct format?

Tags: rest, jersey

I am developing a jersey restful api.
I have a POST method which takes an xml and consumes an xml as well.

Everything seems to work fine in case the input xml is in correct format.
The only problem / query i have is suppose i remove the end tag from an xml when i test it through curl, i am not getting exception or error response?

Can we handle this exception wwhich might have come while marshlling or uinmarshlling explicitly in jersey?

Your input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we give wrong xml as a part of request, jersey rest will just throw a 402 response back and the once calling the webservice should know what 402 means.